# Is it possible to return two variables from context manager/with method?

Tags: python

is it possible to return two variables from the context manager? The use case is getting the mysql connection and cursor at the same time, so that I can commit the connection and close the connection/cursor all upon exiting:

```
class DatabaseConnect:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __enter__(self):
        self.cnx = databaseConnect(self.name)
        self.cursor=self.cnx.cursor()
        return self.cnx, self.cursor
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.cnx.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnx.close()
```

```
   with DatabaseConnect("QueryableCases") as cnx, cursor:
           ~~~~do something with database~~~
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses:

```
with DatabaseConnect("QueryableCases") as (cnx, cursor):
```

Otherwise, `cursor` is parsed as a second context manager, rather than `(cnx, cursor)` getting parsed as a target.

Comment: You should approve this answer if it works for you.